# Getting error "vector size 216 is too big"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

my code fetches keywords from my browser, which are 40-50 keywords long. It successfully fetched a lot of keyword lists, but on one of them I got this error: `RenderWidgetHostImpl::OnSwapCompositorFrame, LatencyInfo vector size 216 is too big.`

This is the line of code that recieves the keyword list from Chrome

```
keywords = pyperclip.paste().split(",")
```

I searched online for the error, people advised to divide the data to small chunks.  My question is, how do I divide the data I am going to fetch from Chrome.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if you are getting this error on the mentioned line. Can you update the question with the _error trace logs_ and more of your code trials including what `paste()` is all about?